# Why mathematica Minimize function cannot handle Integers constraint in this case?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I am an electrical engineer and sudenly a problem of this form appear during my research
[image]

For this kind of problem, Mathematica can work just fine. But as soon as I as the Integers option then I cannot receive the solution

[image]

Therefore, my question is where did I do wrong and how to avoid this issue.

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Please post the actual Mathematica code, not (just) screenshots of it.

Comment: Look for `LinearProgramming`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integers I'd do two steps: first, find out what values of $x$ and $y$ are allowed,

```
xy = Solve[x + y == 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, {x, y}, Integers]
(*    {{x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}}    *)
```

Then, find the minimum of $A x+B y$ over the discrete solutions:

```
Assuming[A > 0 && B > 0, Min[A x + B y /. xy] // FullSimplify]
(*    Min[A, B]    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in two steps

```
mini=Minimize[{A x + B y, x + y == 1, x >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}]
(* real solution*)

mini // Simplify[#, {  Element[{x, y}, Integers]}] &
(* integer solution...*)
```

[image]

The cases `x->1/2`,`y->1/2`  have to be excluded (don't know how...)

Comment: This is wrong. The minimum over integers is, quite generally, not found by minimizing over the reals first and specializing to the integers second. Minimizing over integers is MUCH harder than that.